# how to search through only div with a certain class name on a page

Tags: javascript, jquery

lets say I wanted to search through divs with a certain class name.and if the divs dont have a certain id I want to add a class to them. ex.

```
<div id ="1" class="head"></div>
<div id ="2" class="head"></div>
<div id ="3" class="head"></div>

  if(div.id != "1")
 {
  add class to all divs not = 1
 }
```

how would this work thank you

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### jQuery

You can use this code to do that...

```
$('div.head:not(#1)').addClass('some-class');
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ymDWE/).

For better performance, use...

```
$('div.head').not('#1').addClass('some-class');
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LQCSg/).

---

#### Without jQuery

For modern browsers...

```
[].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('div.head')).filter(function(element) {
    return element.id != 1;
}).forEach(function(element) {
    element.classList.add('some-class');
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pTrWm/).

You could drop the `filter()` and use `:not()`, like [Zeta's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9285745/31671).

For our lovable older IEs...

```
var divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div'),
    divsLength = divs.length;

for (var i = 0; i < divsLength; i++) {
    if (divs[i].id != '1' && ~divs[i].className.search(/\bhead\b/)) {
        divs[i].className += ' some-class';    
    }
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CZPtE/).

Depending on how far you need to support, you could always use [`document.getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementsByClassName) so long as you know you will be required to filter `div` elements if other elements may contain the same class name and you must have `div` exclusively.

---

Additionally, an `id` attribute can not start with a number, according to the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-name).

Comment: Thorough!  Also, seconded on the "Don't use numbers for IDs"

Comment: the not doesn't seem to be working just to be clear the not is for the id right? im trying to match a class and add a new class where an id != something

Comment: what does this weird symbol do `~divs[i]`?

Comment: @ajax333221 It inverts the bits in a `Number`.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var result = document.querySelectorAll('div.head:not(#validID)');
for(var i = 0; i < result.length; ++i)
    result[i].className += ' yourClassName';
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9rSYT/). This won't require jQuery. If you prefer jQuery, see [alex answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9285714/1139697).

Comment: My answer doesn't require jQuery either :P +1 I forgot `:not()` can be used with `querySelectorAll()`.

Comment: ... but it does require browser support, and versions of IE older than 9 will not handle this, I believe.

Comment: @alex: Yeah, after your edit :P. Your original answer consisted only of the jQuery version ;). But nvm, I didn't know the [].slice trick, that's a cool one.

Comment: @Zeta I answered for jQuery first because the question was tagged with it. Then I like to answer without jQuery too, for completeness :)

Comment: @alex: That's the reason I provided the pure JS version, the question was also with 'javascript' :D. Although I forgot the support of older browsers - again :/.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('div.head[id!="1"]').addClass('myClass');
```